# Is it possible to delete sda1 or sda2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, partitioning

I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. I tried to install many times, but when the page of installation to choose the partition comes every time I get confused. 4 partitions are shown there. But in the "My Computer"(of Windows) there are 3 partitions - C,D and E. In the below figure the C partition is shown correctly, and the D and E partitions are not shown separately, they are shown in a combined form. I will provide screen shot of it here :

[image]

Can I delete either sda1 or sda2. If yes, how ?

Comment: If you delete `sda1` you would delete your boot partition. if you delete `sda2` you delete the EFI partition. You want both of those partitions if you want a working Windows directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried that recently. I have done that many times without problems until it was windows-8 which makes it almost impossible. you can google it there are even class action lawsuits (in Spain for example) because microsoft is actively trying to prevent it.
The problem is that the booting process will not offer the choice of Os's.
Even on separate disks W8 will hijack the boot or hang. I ended up disconnecting the w8 drive.
if you have the W8 install disk, you can erase the whole disk, install ubuntu and virtual box (oracle) then have a virtual install of w8. I did that for W7 and XP it's great.

Comment: How is this accepted? Works for others: http://apcmag.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-8-and-linux.htm

Comment: chris: this link confirms in a way that the ubuntu process (with w8 already installed) will not work. it describe starting with a blank disk and installing GRUB to take control of the booting process instead of the microsoft boot. if you have an installable version of W8 the virtualbox solution should be perfect for him (copy and paste between OS's etc...)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: thanks for that most interesting answer by http://askubuntu.com/users/7035/luis-alvarado .   the short answer to the original question by TomJ is : it's not gonna work (resizing from ubuntu like that) - the spanish version of W8 has probably been amended because of the lawsuit. The comments that users resent microsoft when they realize how far they are willing to go to block linux is also instructive. kudos to Luis Alvarado for his answer, I will try it one day although I'm quite happy with Linux only and Windows in virtualization (Oracle Vbox)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to get separate disk for Ubuntu. Small disks are really cheap now (almost free!) and that would be much safer for you.

Do not remove those partitions until you are 100% sure what they contain!

Comment: What do you mean by "separate disk" and "small disks" ?

Comment: Your computer can have more than one disk attached - so basically get another, physical disk. Small: 500GB? However, 40GB will be enough!

Comment: I want to install Ubuntu on my same disk on which I installed Windows. What to do then ?

Comment: Resize your /dev/sda4 - which seems to be in weird format so you must be extremely careful! -  to get some free disk space. This is not easy if you are doing for the first time and there is real possibility to lose your Windows 8 installation! DO BACKUP!

Comment: I have done resizing the sda4 many times. Its a wastage of time. Things will be same as in the screen shot after the resize. Is it due to any problem of my hard disk ?

Comment: If things are the same after you have resized sda4 (i.e. the screenshot in the question is the same), that indicates with certainty that you have NOT resized sda4.

Comment: Possible if you know how to: http://apcmag.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-8-and-linux.htm

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Ok. If so, can you explain how to resize sda4 ?